How to Show Style Manager Tool Window
I cannot for the life of me, see how to display the style manager tool window.
I tried to find Style Manager in the Toolbars and Other Windows submenus which appear after clicking on the View menu, but could not find it.
It used to appear docked on the left next to Toolbox and Server Explorer, now I cannot get it to be displayed.
It should look like this blog shows, but the blog doesn't show you how to enable/display it.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/manage-styles-tool-window/

Regarding the problem you encounter, it depends on the project you created and the version of visual studio. You can refer to the following:

Manage Styles are functionalities enabled by the Web Forms designer within Visual Studio. However, they are not applicable to CSHTML files as the designer does not support them: c# - VS 2012 Apply Styles and Manage Styles menu options are missing - Stack Overflow
If you are using a newer version of Visual Studio or creating an ASP.NET Core project, there may not be built-in "Manage Styles" functionality.
Newer versions of Visual Studio and ASP.NET Core project templates often focus on code editing and debugging rather than providing a visual view of the design. This means that, unlike the "Manage Styles" feature in the Web Forms designer, ASP.NET Core projects do not provide similar style management tools.


Solved : Thank you I found the way to access the manage styles tool window via the View menu...
